# Databases for storing coordinate based nodes and relationships

Tags: database-design, geospatial, graph-databases, spatial-data, nosql

**I've been reading about Neo4j**, and am currently experimenting with it in NodeJs.

Are there any other note worthy graph or spatial databases that are better equip for coordinate based entities and relationships. I currently prototyping coordinate based relationships with player entities in a game.

Ultimately I am looking for a technology for storing coordinate nodes that relate to a central hub which services set a polygon (Telecom - CLLI).

Basic Example (Fictional Data):

[image]

I am relatively new to databases outside of the traditional RDBMS. So any guidance or reading will is greatly apprenticed.

Comment: Since you mention Neo4j, are you aware of the [neo4j-spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) plugin? Neo4j-spatial implements an in graph RTree index for efficient geospatial queries. I wrote a few posts about using neo4j-spatial [here](http://www.lyonwj.com/using-neo4j-spatial-and-leaflet-js-with-mapbox/) and [here](http://www.lyonwj.com/mapping-the-worlds-airports-with-neo4j-spatial-and-openflights-part-1/).

Comment: Thank you, I asked this the day before Christmas (probably not the greatest idea), but I am glad you got to me. I will be reading those articles. Thank you for the references :)  I wasn't aware that spatial plugin that makes Neo4j much more appealing for this project.

Comment: @WilliamLyon your two links are broken. Could you please update them. I am having a similar equiry and I hope your resources will offer an insight into what I need. thanks in advance

Comment: @moaxaca the links are [here](http://www.lyonwj.com/using-neo4j-spatial-and-leaflet-js-with-mapbox) and [here](http://www.lyonwj.com/mapping-the-worlds-airports-with-neo4j-spatial-and-openflights-part-1)